# How do I resolve the following error, "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'John Mayer' to data type int"?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We would like our administrators to select a user from the dropdownlist and have the role or roles associated with that user be displayed in a checkbox.

When I attempt to run the code below, I get

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'John Mayer' to data type int

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Below is code I am using.

```
'//Markup
<p>
     <b>Select a User:</b> 
     <asp:DropDownList ID="UserList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
          DataTextField="UserName" DataValueField="LoginId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserList_SelectedIndexChanged"> 

     </asp:DropDownList> 
</p> 
<p> 
    <div class="roleList">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="RoleList" runat="server">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>

'//CodeBehind
Public Sub PopulateUserList()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select LoginId,UserName from tblLogin", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString))
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        UserList.DataSource = ddlValues
        UserList.DataValueField = "LoginId"
        UserList.DataTextField = "UserName"
        UserList.DataBind()

        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub UserList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim conn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

        Dim sql As String = "select UserRoles from tblLogin where userName = " + UserList.SelectedValue

        Dim AD As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        AD.Fill(ds, "table")

        RoleList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        RoleList.DataTextField = "UserRoles"
        RoleList.DataValueField = "LoginId"
        RoleList.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to retrieve also the LoginID from the table and not only the UserRoles

```
Protected Sub UserList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim conn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

    Dim sql As String = "select LoginId, UserRoles from tblLogin " + 
                        "where userName = @uname"

    Dim AD As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    AD.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname",  UserList.SelectedItem.Text)
    AD.Fill(ds, "table")

    RoleList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    RoleList.DataTextField = "UserRoles"
    RoleList.DataValueField = "LoginId"
    RoleList.DataBind()
```

Comment: marc_s, thanks.

2 questions. Any ideas why I can only select the first option on the dropdownlist? Even when I select another option, only the first checkbox value is displayed.

And how do I get the checkbox pre-checked?

Comment: @Kenny sorry, I can't help on this, but how many users are retrieved by your query? (And use the @ prefix in front of the user name if you want the user notified)

Comment: I believe I did use the prefix. It is my understanding you can only use it once.

In any case Steve, just for our testing, 5 users populate the dropdownlist.

So, we want to be able to select user1 and see his/her role displayed in checkbox.

So far, only value for the first option on the dropdownlist is getting displayed regardless of what user you select from the dropdownlist

Comment: Ok, I got the code to show different checkboxes for different options selected from dropdownlist.

I guess I will have to figure out a way to have the automatically checked as soon as the role for a user is selected.